# jQuery $.ajax post to PHP in the same file not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This the code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( ".button" ).click(function() {

        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            //url: '', // url is empty because I'm working in the same file
            data: {'action': clickBtnValue},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
            alert("action performed successfully"); //this alert is fired
            }

    });

});
});
</script>

<div>Button clicked:
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'insert':
            echo "select button!";
            break;
        case 'select':
            echo "insert button!";
            break;
    }
}
?>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="insert" />
<input type="submit" class="button" name="select" value="select" />
```

In the inspector I can see a posted value, so why  `echo "insert button!";` or `echo "select button!";` are not working?

Comment: Is the value of action depending on the ajax response? Since you are firing an ajax request, `$_POST` will not be set.

Comment: Why would anything be shown in the div? Your success function doesn't do anything except make an alert. The `alert` function doesn't modify the DOM to add content to a div.

Comment: why you thinking its not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must change the content in the div in the javascript, as you're doing with the alert().
If  you're working on the same file, the PHP should be at the beginning of the file.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'insert':
            echo "insert button!";
            break;
        case 'select':
            echo "select button!";
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
?>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".button" ).click(function() {
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            //url: '', // url is empty because I'm working in the same file
            data: {'action': clickBtnValue},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                alert("action performed successfully"); //this alert is fired
                $('div#result').text('Button clicked: ' + result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="result"></div>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="insert" />
<input type="submit" class="button" name="select" value="select" />
```

Comment: it's ok, but the echo "insert button!"; or echo "select button!"; ar not working

Comment: Just tried, and it's working perfectly. When you click on the button : 
1. the javascript send the post request
2. PHP check the post action and echo the response ("select button!" or "insert button!")
3. the javascript receives the response and put it in the div

It should be working

Comment: yes it's working, thank you, just the `result` contains html code!
<style>body</style><div>.....select button!

Comment: That's why you have to put the PHP to the top of the file, and add the exit(), so the rest of the file isn't processed.